# A brace in an equation to say both variables are equal to the same value

Tags: equations, positioning

Say I had;

```
 \begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
     x = 0 \\
     y = 0 \\
     z = 0
    \end{cases}
    \qquad \text{and} \qquad
    \begin{cases}
     x = a \\
     y = a \\
     z = b
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
```

How could I insert a brace ( } ) in the second 'cases' to say x and y are equal to a. (i.e. } = a ).

I hope this is clear, if not I can sketch it out - just let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open it with `\left.`, e.g.

```
\left. 
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}
\right\rbrace = a
```

or,

```
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{l}
\left. 
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}
\right\rbrace = a\\
z = b
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

A very short code, with an `rcases` environment, from `mathtools`, nested in a `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
 x = 0 \\
 y = 0 \\
 z = 0
\end{cases}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\begin{cases}
    \begin{rcases}
     x\\
     y
    \end{rcases} = a\\
 z = b
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you're looking for.
Does this answer your question?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \left\lbrace
        \begin{array}{l}
            \left.\begin{array}{l}
                x \\ 
                y \\ 
            \end{array}\right\rbrace = a \\ 
            z = b \\ 
        \end{array}\right.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]